# How to read smtlib2 strings using Z3 C++ api?

Tags: z3

I want to create an `expr` object from a given SMTLIB2 file. I can see a `Z3_parse_smtlib_string` function in the C examples. Is there a wrapper for that in the `expr` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Z3 C++ API does not explicitly provide this functionality as part of the expr class. However, the C++ API can be used alongside the C API, i.e., the function `Z3_parse_smtlib_string` (or ...`_file`) can be used to achieve this. Note that this function returns a `Z3_ast`, which must be converted to an `expr` object to get back to the C++ "world".

A simple example:

```
#include <z3++.h>

...

context ctx;
Z3_ast a = Z3_parse_smtlib2_file(ctx, "test.smt2", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);    
expr e(ctx, a);
std::cout << "Result = " << e << std::endl;
```

Since the `Z3_parse_smtlib2_*` functions do not perform error checking, no exception will be thrown upon errors. This can be achieved by calls to `context::check_error()`.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523407/z3-parse-smtlib-string-usage-issues

Answer (score 0):

You can use Z3 Java API for the same.

Way 1:
When you have SMT-LIB2 file, you can use method "parseSMTLIB2File" in Z3.

Ref Link:
https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classcom_1_1microsoft_1_1z3_1_1_context.html#abe4ef252462f964549e13344cd832364

Way 2:
When you have SMT-LIB2 string, you can use the method "parseSMTLIB2String" in Z3.

Ref Link:
https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classcom_1_1microsoft_1_1z3_1_1_context.html#ae6a8e05f503789a6737b7014f0521b2a