# missing modification methods on C++ APIs

Tags: c++, z3

I wanted to make some transformation on a z3::expr object. How can I use `Z3_substitute_vars`, `Z3_translate` and `Z3_substitute_` with the C++ API? They are implemented in C#, but I can't find them in C++. It's very strange that they are not implemented.

I tried to use the C api but without any result, here an example:

```
void substitute(){
z3::context c;
z3::expr a = c.int_const("a");
Z3_ast astA = a;
z3::expr plus = 2*a;
errs() << Z3_ast_to_string(c,plus);
z3::expr b = c.int_const("b");
Z3_ast astB = a;
z3::expr subs(c,Z3_substitute(c,plus,1,&astA,&astB));
errs() << Z3_ast_to_string(c,subs);
}
```

But `a` doesn't get substituted. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out that these functions are absent. 
The C++ wrapper adds conveniences beyond the C API and it 
will be reasonable to add convenciences for these API functions 
as well since you indicate you are using them.

The C++ wrappers can still be used together with the basic C API.
You can therefore call functions, such as Z3_translate and Z3_substitute 
when using the C++ API. A number of other API functions are also not 
present in the C++ wrapper, but the way that existing functions are wrapped 
should give a very good idea how to call remaining functions.

Here are some related posts:

- [z3 C++ API & ite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160468/z3-c-api-ite)
- [How to use enumerated constants after calling of some tactic in Z3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085232/how-to-use-enumerated-constants-after-calling-of-some-tactic-in-z3/15094513#15094513)
- [How to read smtlib2 strings using Z3 C++ api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570784/how-to-read-smtlib2-strings-using-z3-c-api)
- [Wrapping entities from Z3 C API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412711/wrapping-entities-from-z3-c-api/15413490#15413490)

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use the C api, without any result, I edited my question with an example, but it doesn't work, am I using the method wrongly?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your example has a typo:

```
  Z3_ast astB = a;
```

Try

```
  Z3_ast astB = b;
```